# How to center caption in a figure that is flushright?

Tags: beamer, floats, horizontal-alignment, captions

When I flushright a figure in a beamer with two columns, the caption isn't centered in the figure, which creates an odd misalignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{.5\textwidth}   
            \flushright
            \begin{figure}
                \flushright
                \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image}
                \caption{something}
            \end{figure}
            
        \column{.5\textwidth} 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item something 
                \item something 
                \item something 
            \end{itemize}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternativley you can put the caption  inside a minipage the same width as the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `caption` package:

```latex
\usepackage{caption}
```

And you should set

```latex
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin={0.4\linewidth,0pt}}
```

before the

```latex
\caption{something}
```

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\flushright
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin={0.4\linewidth,0pt}}
\caption{something}
\end{figure}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item something
\item something
\item something
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid running into this problem, if you make your column as wide as you want the image to be, e.g. 0.5 x 0.6 = 0.3. You can use an empty column to fill the space which will get freed by making the column smaller.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame Title}
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                \caption{something}
            \end{figure}
      \end{column}         
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item something 
                \item something 
                \item something 
            \end{itemize}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a minipage.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}

\begin{columns}

\column{.5\textwidth}   

\begin{figure}
  \flushright
  \begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{something}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
            
\column{.5\textwidth} 

\begin{itemize}
  \item something 
  \item something 
  \item something 
\end{itemize}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid using the second pair of braces for the frame title: it's deprecated syntax.